# How to disable WebStorm semicolon check?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm

How to disable WebStorm semicolon check in Node.js?

I have tried the following method but they do not work:

- Checked out the option `use semicolon to terminate statement`
- Changed JavaScript version to ecma6

Comment: Are you using JSHint, JSLint or JSCS in Webstorm?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
2. `JavaScript | Code style issues | Unterminated statement` -- disable this inspection

You can also reach the same inspection by:

1. Placing caret on problematic place in your Editor and bringing Quick Fix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or by clicking on light bulb icon)
2. Choosing right option in appeared menu (if not sure which one then try step #3 for few of them)
3. <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> (or click on small triangle on the right side) to open submenu
4. Choose desired action

**P.S.**
JSLinh/JSHint and alike may also produce such warnings if you are using these tools.

---

As for the actual code generated by IDE (e.g. when using `Code | Reformat...` or using code completion popup/functionality) -- such option is available at

- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript` (similar path for TypeScript)
- `Punctuation` tab

[image]

Comment: +1 because I was looking for a rule like "enforce semicolons", I would have skimmed straight past a "Unterminated statement" item in the settings.

Comment: I can't believe that we are in 2020, it has been I while since semicolons are not mandatory in JS, I have configured the project as ECMAScript 6, and still Webstorm consideres the absence of the semicolons as an error if I don't set the option suggested here that makes your configuration looks like "OK I have errors in my code but don't highlight them" which is not correct

Answer (score 24):

In Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript, click the `Punctuation` tab on the right hand side pane.

Set

`Don't use` semicolon to terminate statements `always`

This would allow you to check for unterminated statements while not flagging up the missing semicolons.

[image]

Comment: This feels like a more "correct" way than to just disable the inspection.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → Unterminated statement → OFF

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `Webstorm->Preferences->Editor->Code Style->JavaScript   Use semicolon to terminate spaces` works fine for me. Maybe double check what Code Style scheme you are setting that for. Sometimes I have changed code style settings, but for a different scheme than the one being applied to the project in question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Webstorm 2017 its here, you just need to change "use" to "don't use" instead.

[image: Webstorm 2017]

Answer (score 0):

We were also straggling with it all the time. To make our life easier we even commit idea styling file. To make it work for every team member.

Open setting/preferences => search by rule text => disable it.

Once you disabled this or any other rule. To stop it appear again you can add to .gitignore:

```
### Commit specific idea files
.idea/*
!.idea/inspectionProfiles
.idea/inspectionProfiles/*
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
```

I didn't find any better way to configure it. So...

Answer (score 0):

### **JSHint**

check `suprress warnings about missing semicolons` at

`settings -> Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Code Quality Tools -> JSHint => Relaxing options`