# JavaScript code style in WebStorm shows unterminated statement warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.1 on a NodeJS project and cannot seem to figure out some of the code styling issues that keep triggering warnings.

For instance, I get these gray blocks where I haven't terminated a line with a semi-colon, which I don't want to do because that goes against the eslint settings for the project. I add the `;` and I get an eslint warning instead.

[image: unterminated statement]

What setting do I need to change to stop this?

Comment: Search for "unterminated" in Settings

Comment: see answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583771/how-to-disable-webstorm-semicolon-check-in-node-js

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To fix this, change the following setting in `Editor > Inspections` of WebStorm:

[image: Editor > Inspections]]

Comment: This just turns off checking for unterminated statements. How do you actually fix your code so that this goes away? This seems hacky to me...

Comment: @coderade: The OP does say that the `;` raises an ESLint warning if added.

Comment: You should turn off that setting because WebStorm is issuing a false warning. If the statement was not terminated it would not compile or there would be some sort of runtime error, and neither is true.  This can be traced back to the misguided meme about semicolons being required (utterly false).

Comment: @haakon.io There's nothing to fix the code is correct with or without the semicolon

Answer (score 12):

Try the following Steps:

`Ctrl-Shift-A –> Unterminated Statement –> Off`

Answer (score 2):

Also for other unwanted inspection problems press Alt+Enter on highlighted code. Context menu will be shown with suggested solutions, including disabling the inspection.

Answer (score -2):

In my case there was a lot of this "unterminated statement" so I just copy the whole code to editor like notepad, delete everything and copy back from a notepad, and all 'unterminated statement' gone.

To give a bit more background, the code snippets on some sites include additional characters (such as `<200b>` in the snippet below) that are not visible unless it is copy & pasted into a program such as `vi`. The `<200b>` represents a Zero-width space as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

The example below was taken from https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests.

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Header from '../../components/Header'
<200b>
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
<200b>
function setup() {
  const props = {
    addTodo: jest.fn()
  }
<200b>
  const enzymeWrapper = mount(<Header {...props} />)
<200b>
  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper
  }
}
```

I suspect the problem is that the Zero-width space has some impact on how the Jetbrains IDE's apply it to Javascript files, because if I remove the `<200b>` manually from the code and then paste it back into the IDE, then it works.

Probably worthwhile to open a bug report.

Should help, try it. It seems like the issue of some additional not editable symbols.