# WebStorm: how to disable the end statement alert for TypeScript?

Tags: webstorm, tslint

How to disable the warning on ending statement with semicolon?

[image]

My `tslint.config` is as follows:

[image]

I tried to change "semicolon" to false but still the same.

Comment: Are you sure that this is reported by TSLint? How the warning message looks like when you hover over? Maybe it's done by IDE itself (built-in inspection). Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584542/783119 for IDE based inspection.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's done by IDE, and I fixed it per your instructions. Thanks a ton!