# WebStorm gives me warnings about missing semicolons even though TSLint says to never use them

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, tslint

Here's an image showing my TSLint config (right) and a warning (left). I know on the right it says to apply code style from TSLint, but even after I say "Yes," these warnings are still there.

[image]

I believe the `"semicolon": [true, "never"]` means never require semicolons.

How do I get WebStorm to respect this setting to never use semicolons, and why isn't reading this setting from TSLint?

Comment: is it only a few lines or every line?

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584542/783119

Comment: @depperm seems like every line to me.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be the IDE's code inspections, you can check if `Unterminated statement` rule is enabled under `Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> JavaScript -> Code style issues`. It ignores the rules in third-party linters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can disable **Unterminated statement** inspection in **Preferences | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | Code style issues** to get rid of the warning.
Note that since 2017.1.x this inspection respects **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation** settings: if **use semicolons** == **Do not use**, inspection only highlights suspicious statements. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24627 for details.

And [importing code style settings from TSLint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html#ws_tslint_import_code_style) sets **use semicolons** to **Do not use always** if you have `"semicolon": [true, "never"]` in your config. Did you try importing settings?

Comment: `Did you try importing settings?` Yes.  So are you saying in this one particular case, WebStorm overrides the TSLint settings?

Comment: didn't say anything of this kind.