# How to disable highlights in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How to disable highlights after functions or statements?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not written in English.

Comment: Those places... that looks like a warning about missing semicolon `;`. 1) Check what system reports them -- is that your linter (ESList, TSLint or whatever) or actually PhpStorm -- hover over and see what the tooltip will say; 2) Once you know that -- configure your linter/Code Style in PhpStorm (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584542/783119)